# Read records from joining Hive tables with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

We can easily read records from a Hive table in Spark with this command:

```
Row[] results = sqlContext.sql("FROM my_table SELECT col1, col2").collect();
```

But when I join two tables, such as:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2 from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

How to retrive the records from the above join query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SparkContext.sql`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/658f66e6208a52367e3b43a6fee9c90f33fb6226/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L816) method always returns `DataFrame` so there is no practical difference between `JOIN` and any other type of query.

You shouldn't use `collect` method though, unless fetching data to the driver is really a desired outcome. It is expensive and will crash if data cannot fit in the driver memory.

Comment: Yeah, use dataframe is correct. But I have two databases, one is default and the other is my_database. When I excute the query, it says that default database have no table like 'my_table'. How to make spark use my own databse. Use my_database.mytable (like using schema in oracle) ?